# Why is this answer not spam?

Tags: discussion, answers, spam, specific-answer

When viewing some questions in the [blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blocked) tag, inspired by the burnination discussion regarding that tag i stumbled across this answer: [Why my website is blocked on Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151297/why-my-website-is-blocked-on-facebook/49735088#49735088).

> Why is my [website blocked on facebook](https://unorthodox.tech/website-blocked-by-facebook/)?
>
> I had the same issue with my site, and managed to resolve it so i decided to write an article on how i managed it. It pretty much involved me submitting my site to two different appeal links, submitting ads for my site then appealing them when they were denied multiple times and spamming the facebook developer forums.
>
> You can view the step by step instructions, along with links to all of the resources i used in my article. Hope it helps guys, feel free to drop me an email if you're still struggling, i know it can be frustrating.

It is posted by an account that is linked to the URL, and by the name of it the account represents a company. It is also the only answer from this account. To me this looks like a clear case of self-promoting of this users website. Which to me counts as spam. My spam flag got disputed though. I don't take this as a sign that this answer should stay, but apparently it shouldn't be removed as spam?

Comment: Because the user disclosed their affiliation. And the post has enough information as to be considered an answer on itself without accessing the external resource. Not a great answer, but not spam either.

Comment: @yivi I disagree with the statement that there is any information in the answer itself. It mentions step by step instructions, but not what they are. There is no way to find out other than clicking that link. If/when the link dies, the answer is pretty much useless. I'd call that NAA.

Comment: @JAD I guess that this part _" It pretty much involved me submitting my site to two different appeal links, submitting ads for my site then appealing them when they were denied multiple times and spamming the facebook developer forums."_ could be considered an answer. I agree that it's a lousy answer, and it is probably a lousy question (haven't checked). But those are the breaks. Vote on the answer, maybe flag the question.

Comment: @JAD, indeed the answer here barely summarises the blogpost, leaving out all links etc.

Comment: @yivi, question is already on-hold

Comment: This problem started with the question.  That SO cannot effectively help Facebook victims left out in the cold by murky unexplained policies and non-existing company support has been abundantly obvious for quite a while already.

Comment: @yivi fair enough

Comment: I think it should be on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The description of the spam flag says

> Exists only to promote a product or service, [does not disclose the author's affiliation.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

This post does disclose affiliation:

> i decided to write an article on how i managed it.

It doesn't state explicitly that that article is the one linked to, but it doesn't take a huge leap of mind to conclude that it must be. Because validated spam flags carry some hefty penalties, yours was declined.

Comment: Well then I missed that last part of the link.